# Invaled Object Name exception when i try to insert data to database via Android App

Tags: android, sql, database, azure, object

Solution: If you are using jdbc connection string directly from Azure SQL Server, change "database=..." after database url as "databaseName=..." and it solves the problem.

I am trying to use Azure SQL Database on my Android Application.

```
Connection con = basla.returnCon();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('lol') ");
```

"basla" is my AsyncTask object and returns connection by getCon() to "con".

```
 Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

 this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://walky.database.windows.net:1433;database=Walky;user=***@walky;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");
```

and this is my connection string, as you can see default database Connection is "Walky".

[Walky Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ePn.png)

and there is " test " table at my Database.

now when i try

```
statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('lol') ");
```

this, throws exception "Invaled Object Name 'test'

```
statement.executeQuery("USE Walky INSERT INTO test VALUES ('lol') ");
```

this, throws exception about that i can't use " USE " statement and i have to create another connection for another database.

```
statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO [Walky].[dbo].[test] VALUES ('lol') ");
```

this, throws exception about that Walky.dbo.test is not a compatible reference for my sql server version.

I also tried to `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`.

I can insert data by SQL Server Management Studio but can't do it with my Android Application.

is there anyting that i am missing or doing wrong?

Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your Query is for Inserting data, you should use `executeUpdate` - assuming that your query string is correct in terms of your table structure, you could do something like this:
  //change your connection string to:

```
`this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://walky.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=Walky;user=***@walky;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");`
    ...
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    int rowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('lol') ");
    //here you could check rowsAffected as an indication that the values were persisted
```

The method `executeUpdate` returns an integer representing the number of rows affected by the SQL statement and should be used when you have INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE SQL statements.

Look at the more examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html). I hope this helps.

Comment: Nope again it throws java.sql.SQLException : Invaled object name 'test'.

Comment: And you say the table `test` exists in your `Walky` database? try changing your connection string to specifying `databaseName` instead of just `database` like you have it. Your connection string will look like:  `this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://walky.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=Walky;user=***@walky;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you!!! Changing "database" to "databaseName" is solved this issue. Adding solution to my post.

Comment: Good. I am glad this solved your issue. Thanks for accepting, please also vote the answer if you found it useful.